# Dissapear text in textbox in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I made a textbox of name tbFirstNumber

When i enter any value in that textbox , i want that Value to dissapear

I am using C# window form application in visual studio 2008

```
private void tbFirstNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: You want the value of what to disappear? Could you please elaborate and explain?

Comment: For the people who are smashing the down-vote, please consider explaining why you have done so.

Comment: I fail to see the purpose of a `text box` that does not display text. Moreover, it "deletes" all the text that I write into it.

Comment: Probably he wants a read only text box in which user is not allowed to write anything

Comment: @Anand Why not use a Label then?

Comment: Is it possible that you want a ["cue" TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27853/CueProvider)? I.e. a box which has some placeholder text (a "hint") which should disappear when user starts to type? Because you can get that "for free" from the OS, by sending a `EM_SETCUEBANNER` message to a text box.

Comment: Just confirm me, are you referring to enter the text into database, but it should not be viewed while typing? if that is the case, in the properties you can set the password char to space(single blank space). By using space as password char, while entering the data, it is not viewed in the form, but it will be stored in the stored in the database as text you entered only.

Answer (score 1):

```
tbFirstNumber.Text = "";
```

Just set it to empty on text changed event.

If you want that user is not allowed to enter any text, you can make the textbox as read only.
Set the TextBox control's ReadOnly property to true.

```
tbFirstNumber.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to do that as he's got a TextChanged event.

Comment: +1 for explaining and for the readonly comment.

Comment: yeah, not very clear what he wants. Its just a guess :)

Comment: He clearly writes "When I enter any value in that textbox", which means that the text box cannot be read only.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to hook in to the KeyPress event.

```
 private void tbFirstNumber_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
   // Stop the character from being entered into the control
   e.Handled = true;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tbFirstNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 tbFirstNumber.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Clear the value of the text box

this.tbFirstNumber.Text = ""